# How can i make my arguments my starting and ending number in my loop

Tags: bash

[my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGjvu.png)

how can i make the first argument become the first number in the loop and make my second argument become the second number in the loop?

Comment: Add your script to your question (no image, no links). Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

We can use a new variable $counter to avoid changing the value of your variables as follows. Obviously you can do other things with the values than echo them to STDOUT.

```
#!/bin/bash
bhuser1=2
bhuser2=5
counter=$bhuser1
while [ $counter -le $bhuser2 ]
do
  echo $counter
  ((counter++))
done
```

output

```
2
3
4
5

[Execution complete with exit code 0]
```

I have found the following tutorial helpful: https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php

Answer (score 0):

The range expression `{ .. }` unfortunately does not accept variables, because range expansion happens before parameter expansion. You have to implement a countint loop explicitly, something like.

```
for ((i=bhuser1; i<=bhuser2; i+=1))
do
  ....
done
```